# Потеря данных при извлечении из БД MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, запрос

Есть метод с запросом к БД:

```
public ModelGame CreateGame(ModelGame newgame)
{
   int newGameId;
        string sqlStr = "insert into game(game_name) values ('" + newgame.GameName + "'); select scope_identity();";

        using (var PCDataBase = new DbModel())
        {
            newGameId = PCDataBase.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlStr);
            PCDataBase.SaveChanges();
        }

   return GetOneGame(newGameId);
}
```

так вот, в переменную newGameId мне приходит не полное значение айдишника, а лишь первая его цифра (к примеру создается запись в таблице БД по номером 38, а приходит лишь цифра 3). Кто-то может сказать в чем подвох?

Дело в том, что такой-же запрос из Managemend Studio возвращает все правильно...

Comment: *Никогда не используйте строковую конкатенацию для формирования SQL-запроса!*

Comment: У вас случайно на таблицу game триггеров не понавешано?

Comment: Не извлечении, а при вставке.

Comment: можете показать свойства колонка game_name?

Comment: ID-вставки в sql по другому. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187342.aspx

Comment: @nick_n_a через `scope_identity` - это правильный метод, а через `identity` - неправильный, т.к. он может вернуть id *какой-то другой* вставки, а не той, что была выше по коду - об этом сказано по вашей же ссылке :)

Comment: покажите код PCDataBase.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand. при последующих вставках все еще возвращает 3, десять раз подряд, потом начинает возвращать 4? Или возвращает 4, 5, 6 - вместо 39, 40, 41? может вы просто не в ту базу вставяете?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov как мне тогда запрос создать в котором есть динамический параметр.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov да у меня есть триггеры на этой таблице

Comment: @РоманТимохов почитайте справку по ExecuteSqlCommand

Comment: @PashaPash при переходе через десяток все равно приходит 3